# Postgresql incremental and conditional filtering

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table

```
 ID    value    user      stock
----|--------|---------|---------
  1 |   10   | mark    |  AAPL
  2 |   20   | rob     |  GOOG
  3 |   30   | mark    |  AAPL
  4 |  -40   | mark    |  AAPL
  5 |  -10   | rob     |  GOOG
  6 |   25   | mark    |  GOOG
  7 |    5   | mark    |  GOOG
  8 |   45   | mark    |  AAPL
```

I would like to build a query (possibly without using any PGSQL function) that returns the rows shown below. It should start in order (ID ASC) summing "value" column grouped by user,stock. If the temporary sum is 0, all the previous rows (for that group) will be discarded.

```
 id    value    user      stock
----|--------|---------|---------
  2 |   20   | rob     |  GOOG
  5 |  -10   | rob     |  GOOG
  6 |   25   | mark    |  GOOG
  7 |    5   | mark    |  GOOG
  8 |   45   | mark    |  AAPL
```

I think that OVER (PARTITION BY) and WINDOW function should be used

`SELECT *, SUM(value) OVER w AS scm 
        FROM "mytable" 
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY user,stock ORDER BY id ASC)`

this returns next table

```
 ID    value    user      stock    scm
----|--------|---------|---------|-------
  1 |   10   | mark    |  AAPL   | 10
  2 |   20   | rob     |  GOOG   | 20
  3 |   30   | mark    |  AAPL   | 40
  4 |  -40   | mark    |  AAPL   |  0
  5 |  -10   | rob     |  GOOG   | 10
  6 |   25   | mark    |  GOOG   | 25
  7 |    5   | mark    |  GOOG   | 30
  8 |   45   | mark    |  AAPL   | 45
```

So this should be a good starting point, because it shows that APPL for mark is 0 (id=4) and for that group (AAPL,mark) I should keep all the following rows.
The rule is: for each group (stock,user) keep all the rows following the last row with scm=0

Comment: What version of postgresql are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7bb42/1)

```
with s as (
    select *,
        count(scm = 0 or null) over w z
    from (
        select *,
            sum(value) over w as scm
        from mytable
        window w as (partition by "user", stock order by id asc)
    ) s
    window w as (partition by "user", stock order by id asc)
)
select *
from
    s
    inner join
    (
        select max(z) z, "user", stock
        from s
        group by "user", stock
    ) z using (z, "user", stock)
where scm > 0
order by s.user, s.stock, id
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following I think would get you want you want.  Basically it will perform the following:

1. Use the SQL statement you have to compute the cumulative sums.
2. Compute the minimum ID that should be displayed for each `(username, stock)` group.
3. Select from the original SQL cumulative sum and filter out any IDs lower than the minimum ID.

```sql
WITH sums AS (
  SELECT id, value, username, stock, SUM(value) OVER w AS scm
    FROM "mytable"
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY user,stock ORDER BY id ASC)),

minimum_ids AS (
  SELECT username, stock, MAX(id) as minimum_id
    FROM sums
   WHERE scm <= 0
   GROUP BY username, stock)

SELECT sums.id, sums.value, sums.username, sums.stock, sums.scm
  FROM sums
  LEFT JOIN minimum_ids
    ON (sums.username = minimum_ids.username
        AND sums.stock = minimum_ids.stock)
 WHERE (minimum_ids.minimum_id IS NULL OR sums.id > minimum_ids.minimum_id)
 ORDER BY id;
```